# Merge old exchange contacts to iCloud (with iPhone)

Tags: iphone, icloud, contacts, exchange

I'm trying to export my contact from my old exchange account to my iCloud account. The problem is that I do not have access to my exchange account anymore. All I have, is my contacts saved on my iphone. I tried syncing my iCloud contacts and merge everything, but I get a message saying that exchange contacts can't be merge. Since I don't have access to my exchange account anymore I also can't export them from outlook to a csv file.

So basically, is there an app or a trick to get old exchange contacts saved in the iPhone to iCloud?

Thanks!

Comment: Check the Exchange contacts closely. They should be empty if you no longer have access to Exchange. :'( They may have remained as placemarkers if you added anything to these contacts that could not sync back to Exchange.

Comment: No, I have checked, They are still all there. I suspect that the iPhone saves them locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get different apps to do this. I have used 'Contact Mover' and it worked fine. You can sync your exchange contacts to your phone which copies them over.  You can also then get an app to merge the duplicates.

My issues is: (Somebody please help me!) I cant seem to find an app to extract all my emails from my iphone that are stored on an exchange I dont have access to anymore. I have been told it can be done but I am yet to find out how.  Anyone know how to extract or copy email data/content from an outlook exchange to icloud?

Answer (score 1):

I would try using [iExplorer](http://www.macroplant.com/iexplorer/tutorials/how-to-access-address-book-contacts-on-iphone.php) to extract the contacts from the iPhone.  It works on Mac or PC, and it has a free trial version that should allow you to do everything you need.

Answer (score 0):

I used Smiling Cloud, it's very good. You sync with the cloud and can recover your contacts anytime. At the same time your contacts may be exported from Exchange to Sim or phone.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how precisely to get Exchange to phone or exchange to SIM?